# DataGridView Column Headers retain Font Size

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

The `DataGridView` automatically adjusts to the size of the form when its maximized, as well as the column width and its contents. I have set the property `AutoSizeColumnsMode` to Fill, ColumnHeadersHeightSize to `AutoSize` and I have set the `ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle` to a specific font style and font size.

It is all well and fine but the Column Headers Font Size keeps on adjusting and I can't seem to find what causes it. I have played with the properties already but to no avail. What I wanted is that the columns and its contents adjust to the width of the form but retain the font size of the column headers, that's all.

I have thought of doing it in code but I would like to know if there is a more elegant solution or if I am missing something.

If there is none, feel free to suggest code in either C# or VB.net